# Roku DVR Strem Url Video Full Length

Tags: roku, brightscript

We have used video node to play channel and we want to take the video length,how can we do that,can you explain?
When video wil completed it's buffer and starts to play we can see the total time of the video but when we try to get that value we are not being able to catch that value,you can see the screenshoot below:
http://prntscr.com/otfif5

Answer (score 0):

You can catch total time by using "**duration**" field of Video node. Suppose "m.video" is the instance of Video node, then you can get the video duration as-

```
duration = m.video.duration
```

Remember that duration will be in seconds and you can get it once the playback begins.

Comment: It  gives the time taken to play the video in second  but i want the actual video length

Comment: what to you mean by "video length"? Please specify.

Comment: i want the Dvr video whole length like some movie legth is 3hour 22minuts and like that, i want that whole length like you can se the screenshot that i have puted in question

Comment: yes, this will provide what you are looking for. Just you have to convert seconds into hours, and minutes. If you are not getting it proper, may be you are missing something in code. I am using this field for same purpose from long time.

Comment: but the problem is i have 1hour and 57min longvideo but it giving second as 10448sec but when we calculate 1hour and 57min into seconds then it only gives 6840second only then how can it be same and in roku developer document it has crearly mentationed that:
duration:The duration of the video being played, specified in seconds. This becomes valid when playback begins and may change if the video is dynamic content, such as a live event.
that means it gives duration taken to played only

Comment: The docs reference, you gave I already included in my answer. As you are saying sometimes duration given by this field and actual duration differ. Even sometimes, value given by this field and shown at roku video player differs by a huge margin. I also observed that. But when we inspected, most of the time, root cause was video content meta data. I am not forcing you to accept whatever I am saying. May be I am wrong. If you find someting better alternate of this, please inform me, so that I can also use that. Thanks.

Comment: it's giving the duration but not the exact one, but also, i also have used this method for now, but don't you think we should find out the best  method?